# Can I relay the bottom three brick rows

Tags: fireplace, brick

So I removed the hearth (3 rows high) of a former fireplace and found that the bottom three rows was sloppily laid, and this hurts my eyes: https://imgur.com/a/q25Gn8W.

Can I safely relay them? If so how should I proceed? The previous owner covered the firebox with bricks so I don't know what it looked like inside, nor how the buildout is fixed/suppoted. From what I can tell the buildout is just one layer of bricks, and behind it is the concrete wall.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is that gonna be exposed when all is said and done?  Personally, my eye would be drawn more to the outline where you put new bricks.

Comment: Yes, that’s how it looks finally. Since the fireplace is no longer functional, it makes little sense to leave the hearth, especially when a new flooring is to be installed.

Comment: And those bricks jutting out perpeendicularly will remain?

Comment: No, I will either cut them or relay, depending on how I should proceed. Based on my research online, it sounds safest to redo 4 bricks at a time (https://youtu.be/8jL2tRYL5kk). Also by looking at people demolishing their fireplaces, I think there might have been brackets holding the surround and the back wall together.

Comment: You might have luck re-laying the bricks one by one.  I certainly wouldn't try to remove them all at once.

Comment: Thanks Huesmann! I redid only those that were obviously unaligned or broken. It was more work than I expected since there is another wall right behind the surround, so I had to be careful not to cause collateral damage.